# How to fix Unbound Local Error with Selenium TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, error-handling

I have a df with a list of projects and I have an empty df to store errors:

```
error_log = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Project', 'Error'])
```

I have an error logging function that should write a row to the empty df:

```
def log_error(df, df_row, friendly_text, error):
    df = df.append({'Project':df_row['project_name'],
                'Error': friendly_text + ' due to this error: ' + repr(error)},
               ignore_index=True)
    return df
```

When I try to use this function for error handling...

```
for index, row in audit_plan.iterrows():
    try:
        create_project(driver, row)
    except TimeoutException as error:
        error_log = log_error(error_log, row, 'The project was not created', error)
    else:
        try:
            open_project(driver, row) #TimeoutException occurs here
        except TimeoutException as error:
            error_log = log_error(error_log, row, 'The created project was not opened for editing', error)
```

...I get this error when there is a timeout exception on the `open_project()` call:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'error_log' referenced before assignment
```

I have not been able to recreate this without my actual functions/process. Simple examples like this...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

projects = pd.DataFrame([['Project 1', 'AAA'], ['Project 2', 'BBB']], columns=['project_name', 'code'])

error_log = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Project', 'Error'])

def log_error(df, df_row, friendly_text, error):
    df = df.append({'Project':df_row['project_name'],
                    'Error': friendly_text + ' due to this error: ' + repr(error)},
                   ignore_index=True)
    return df

for index, row in projects.iterrows():
    try:
        print(row['project_name'])
    except TimeoutException as error:
        error_log = log_error(error_log, row, 'The project was not created', error)
    else:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'something_not_on_the_page')))
        except TimeoutException as error:
            error_log = log_error(error_log, row, 'The created project was not opened for editing', error)
```

...run flawlessly.

Why am I getting an Unbound Local Error?

Here is the full trace:

```
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<magic-timeit> in inner(_it, _timer)

~\path_to_file\load.py in open_project(driver, dataframe_row)
     59     project_search.send_keys(dataframe_row['Project Title'])
---> 60     WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(text_to_equal((By.CLASS_NAME, 'totalRecords'), '1'))
     61     project_result = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[title="' + dataframe_row['Project Title'] + '"]')))

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\robotics\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 

TimeoutException: Message: 


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-954795f13ce7> in <module>

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\robotics\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2350             with self.builtin_trap:
   2351                 args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2352                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2353             return result
   2354 

<C:\Users\random_username\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\robotics\lib\site-packages\decorator.py:decorator-gen-61> in timeit(self, line, cell, local_ns)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\robotics\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\robotics\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\execution.py in timeit(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1149                     break
   1150 
-> 1151         all_runs = timer.repeat(repeat, number)
   1152         best = min(all_runs) / number
   1153         worst = max(all_runs) / number

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\robotics\lib\timeit.py in repeat(self, repeat, number)
    202         r = []
    203         for i in range(repeat):
--> 204             t = self.timeit(number)
    205             r.append(t)
    206         return r

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\robotics\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\execution.py in timeit(self, number)
    159         gc.disable()
    160         try:
--> 161             timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
    162         finally:
    163             if gcold:

<magic-timeit> in inner(_it, _timer)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'error_log' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback which includes the line with the error.

Comment: Your code appears not to have created the original `error_log` dataframe. The first time you try to pass it to `log_error` it doesn't exist.

Comment: Full trace added. I thought I am creating `error_log` in the first line? `error_log = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Project', 'Error'])`

Comment: I'm confused about how your code runs. You show code at module level but an error that only happens in a function. And it appears to be in a callback somewhere. This is in jupyter, right? It may be easier to debug by running it on the command line.